# I updated Ubuntu to 20.04 Jammy. After update i am unable to update anything at all as i keep getting message given below

Tags: updates, 22.04

I updated ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 jammy. After the update, a red stop sign appeared and I am unable to update anything at all. Whatever I try, I get the following message:

```
E: Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

How to solve? I am basic ubuntu user

Comment: Please check your details; 18.04 was *bionic*, 20.04 was *focal* and 22.04 is *jammy*...  You mention 20.04 but refer to it as *jammy*  (it was *focal*).   The *google* source however is unrelated to any system or upgrade; it's a user-added one as `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is empty (user add files exist there)

Comment: Sorry. I updated from 20.04 to 22.04 Jammy

Comment: Your error tells you the problem is with `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list` this file, and is in line 2.  Someone with `sudo` rights on the system has added that file, as that directory is empty on a clean/new install.  It contains invalid data on line 2 which needs correction, we cannot see what is on it, thus cannot advise on what's there, except it was added by user with `sudo` privileges.

Comment: How to check what is wrong? is there a command that can be given to see whats wrong and i can share the screenshot

Comment: You can `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list` to view what is inside the file, but given its not essential I'd just erase it. Editing and adding a "#" to the beginning of line 2 will turn that line into a comment, meaning that line will be ignored, however the system stopped reading the file at line 2 when an error existed, so subsequent lines may also contain errors too.  Please don't share screenshots, but copy/paste the contents of text files.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information. You can open the file in a text editor and copy&paste the text to your question, formatted as a code block, e.g. by using the `{}` tool of the editor field.

Comment: When i used the Cat /etc command, this is what the screen displayed: deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/stable main

Comment: Your last comment includes a link; try opening that with a browser & you should quickly see what is wrong with it....

Comment: tried opening in browser using link. 404 error (Google) was what came up in response

Comment: The problem is resolved by using this command : sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list